# Modular web application - Debug module code in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, modular-design

I implemented a web shell application that loads multiple modules inside. A module is also a standalone web application. So, practically I have one visual studio solutions opened for the shell application, and a visual studio solution for each module. In order to launch a module from the shell application, I manually copy the dll's of the module in the bin of the shell. 
The problem is that when I run the web shell, the breakpoints that I set in the module are not hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure to include the location where the .pdb files are located, so that your debugger knows where the code is coming from, you could do this with the Debug >> Options and settings menu command, and then include the symbols from where your DLL was built.

Under the Load Symbols command, you can then add the location to the PDB files

[image]

Then you could open the source code from those locations, and set the breakpoints in your running web shell project

Some more info about it you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241613.aspx

Comment: Thank you. It works if I open the source code file manually in the web shell solution and set the breakpoint there. My expectations were that somehow the symbol file should already contain information about the breakpoint that I set in the module solution (before I built the module) and automatically open the file when the breakpoint is hit. Do you know if such a scenario is possible? Because for the developer it would be simpler to debug like this.

Comment: @CristinaAlboni You could enable that by doing Debug >> Attach to process >> and then choose for the process which would run your module. This would allow you to attach to the latest build, and debug directly in your solution (however, if your sources change inbetween, the breakpoints won't be hit)